# Replace fadeIn/fadeOut with animate() to slide left smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jquery and want to rotate a div from right to left, but not able to move it completely however I have tried fadeOut/fadeIn to just give a look, can someone help me to edit my code at http://jsfiddle.net/nAaMV/831/

```js
$(function () {
            $('.slideshow div').hide(); // hide all slides
            $('.slideshow div:first-child').show(); // show first slide
            setInterval(function () {
                        $('.slideshow div:first-child').fadeOut(200)
                                .next('div').fadeIn(200)
                                .end().appendTo('.slideshow');
                    },
                    5000); // slide duration
});
```

```css
#slide1{
    background-color:#ff00ee;    
}
#slide2{
    background-color:#eeff00;    
}
#slide3{
    background-color:#00eeff;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow">
        <div id="slide1">
            <p class="quote">Quote One</p>
            <p class="credit">Person One</p>
        </div>
        <div id="slide2">
            <p class="quote">Quote Two</p>
            <p class="credit">Person Two</p>
            
        </div>
        <div id="slide3">
            <p class="quote">Quote 3</p>
            <p class="credit">Person 3</p>
            
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close with the method you were using. The only thing you needed to do for it to work was to wait for fadeOut animation to end. Simply use the callback and when the animation ends, the callback with be called.

```
$(function () {
    $('.slideshow div').hide(); // hide all slides
    $('.slideshow div:first-child').show(); // show first slide
    setInterval(function () {
        $('.slideshow div:first-child').fadeOut(200, function () {
            $(this).next('div').fadeIn(400).end().appendTo('.slideshow');
        })
    },
    1000); // slide duration
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nAaMV/833/)

Comment: Thank you for looking into and helping me, however I was looking for an alternate method to just slide the div smoothly but currently it is showing with a blink. Can we use animate() in place of fadeOut() and fadeIn(), if yes could you please help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting smooth transition because during the period when jquery was fading in one div and fading out other simultaneously, both div's are present, Due to which the height of parent division is changing.
You will have to do some work for it :

```js
$(function () {
    $('.slideshow div').hide(); // hide all slides
    $('.slideshow div:first-child').show(); // show first slide
 var time = 2000;
    setInterval(function () {
  $('.slideshow div:first-child')
            .fadeOut(time).addClass("ignoresize")
            .next('div').fadeIn(time).removeClass("ignoresize")
            .end().appendTo('.slideshow');
        },
    time + 1000); // slide duration
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
}
.slideshow {
 position:relative;
 background-color:#999;
}
#slide1{
    background-color:#ff00ee;    
}
#slide2{
    background-color:#eeff00;    
}
#slide3{
    background-color:#00eeff;    
}
.ignoresize {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 10;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow">
    <div id="slide1" class="slide">
        <p class="quote">Quote One</p>
        <p class="credit">Person One</p>
    </div>
    <div id="slide2" class="slide">
        <p class="quote">Quote Two</p>
        <p class="credit">Person Two</p>
    </div>
    <div id="slide3" class="slide">
        <p class="quote">Quote 3</p>
        <p class="credit">Person 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit :**
Here is the method to animate divisions from right to left.

```js
$(function () {
    $('.slideshow div').hide(); // hide all slides
    $('.slideshow div:first-child').show(); // show first slide
 var time = 2000;
    setInterval(function () {
  $slidea = $('.slideshow div:first-child');
  $slideb = $slidea.next();
  width = $('.slideshow div:first-child').width();
  $('.slideshow div:first-child').addClass("ignoresize")
   .animate({left: width}, time).hide(0)
   .next().removeClass("ignoresize").show(0)
   .css("left", 0).end().appendTo(".slideshow");
        },
    time + 1000); // slide duration
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
}
.slideshow {
 position:relative;
 background-color:#999;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#slide1{
    background-color:#ff00ee;    
}
#slide2{
    background-color:#eeff00;    
}
#slide3{
    background-color:#00eeff;    
}
.ignoresize {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 10;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow">
    <div id="slide1" class="slide">
        <p class="quote">Quote One</p>
        <p class="credit">Person One</p>
    </div>
    <div id="slide2" class="slide">
        <p class="quote">Quote Two</p>
        <p class="credit">Person Two</p>
    </div>
    <div id="slide3" class="slide">
        <p class="quote">Quote 3</p>
        <p class="credit">Person 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!!

Can we also slide the div from right to left? If yes could you please help me with code.

Comment: @abhishekkumar Yes we can. Here I edited my code to help you animate division from right to left.

Comment: @abhishekkumar you can upvote any good post (once you got enough repo) and accept an answer if it solve your problem (specifically most helpful answer).